# copy data according to the length of the adjucent column

Tags: excel, vba

```
Columns("Q:Q").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("O3" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("P4:P" & lastRow).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("Q4").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

I am trying to insert a column next to Q column, copy the data from P column based on the length of the adjacent column ("O") and paste the data into the inserted column.

Above is the code I am using to achieve this. But the problem is column P and O don't have the same length of data every time.

I am not sure what I am missing here. Someone correct me where I am doing it wrong.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ("O3" & Rows.Count caused problems). Also no need to [select cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?s=1%7C193.8044).

```
Columns("Q:Q").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("P4:P" & lastRow).Copy Range("Q4")
```

Comment: Pleased to hear it. Would you mind accepting the answer which will just take me over the 9k mark?